# How to modify the .te file generated by audit2allow and recompile it into .pp file

Tags: compilation, policy, selinux

I used below command to generate a policy file:

```
ausearch  -ts today |audit2allow -M sample
```

it will generate two files: sample.te and sample.pp

the sampel.te contains lines such as:

```
allow container_t unlabeled_t:dir { add_name create remove_name rename write };
```

I want edit this line to add a "read" permission:

```
allow container_t unlabeled_t:dir { add_name create remove_name rename write read};
```

But I don't know how to compile the .te file into .pp file so that I can apply it (used later in other nodes as well)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*audit2allow* [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/audit2why.1.html) explains how to compile module. If you are not using refence policy macros, you can directly use *checkmodule* (SELinux policy compiler) and *semodule_package* (packager):

```
checkmodule -M -m -o sample.mod sample.te
semodule_package -o sample.pp -m sample.mod
```

If you have reference policy macros in your policy file (used `-R` option for *audit2allow* or added macros in your modifications), you need to have the policy development files (*selinux-policy-dev* package) installed and use the provided makefile:

```
make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile sample.pp
```